# Passing a query to a string without the first char

Tags: c

I have this code that is suppose to receive `args` (query string) and copy it to a string `nome` without the first char (_) as to send it to another function. I know that both `if`s work but it seems to break at the `for` and I do not know why.

```
ESTADO ler_estado(char *args) {
    char nome[strlen(args)-1];
    int i;

    if(strlen(args) == 0)
        return inicializar();

    if(args[0] =='_'){

        for(i=strlen(args); i !=1; i--){
            nome[i]=args[i];
        }

        return lerficheiro(nome);
    } 

    return str2estado(args);
}
```

Comment: What is `ESTADO`? Is it important for your [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

This `for` loop

```
for(i=strlen(args); i !=1; i--){
    nome[i]=args[i];
}
```

copies all characters except first and second (i.e. at indexes `0` and `1`), but since it places the characters at their old positions, the initial two characters end up uninitialized.

You can use `strcpy` with the first character skipped, thus avoiding the `for` loop altogether

```
strcpy(nome, &args[1]);
```

or you can avoid copying in the first place, drop `nome`, and pass `&args[1]` to the function:

```
if (args[0] == '_') {
    return lerficheiro(&args[1]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance as i am still learning. But wont
 if (args[0] == '_') {
    return lerficheiro(&args[1]);
}
Send the first char of args?

Comment: @PedroCastro No, it sends `args` *without* the initial character. The address-of operator returns the address of `args[1]`, the first character after `_`. The rest of `args` array is a null-terminated string. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried but my function ler_ficheiro must have a problem so I cant tell if it is working or not but I trust your answer. Thank you very much for the attention.Ill try to fix my function and tell you if it works. Once again thank you

Comment: @PedroCastro One way to convince yourself that the approach is working is to `printf("%s\n", &args[1])` and see what gets printed.

Comment: I cant print as I am working for web (school work) and it wont appear on my terminal the printf. It is quite inconvenient for me but i do not know svg as to be able to print in the web page, Sorry